# compile 2.6.21 kernel for MIPS32

Tags: configuration, linux-kernel, mips32

Can anybody please help me to compile kernel 2.6.21 for mips32 acrh? Please let me know which option/options should I select from make menuconfig. I have the toolchain installed and the target board is a little endian system.

Thanks in advance,
Souvik

Comment: This depends so much on the details of your target board... do you have any previous linux kernel configuration for it?  If you are completely at a loss, I believe the DDWRT/OpenWRT router packages are a MIPS embedded linux whose configuration you could borrow as a distant starting point, but you'd probably have to do a lot of work to develop a configuration that works for your board's hardware.  Usual initial goal would be to get a stable (if not necessarily full speed) processing environment with DRAM refreshing and mapped and get a serial driver working so you can see early boot messages..

Comment: Also you may need to think about bootup and flashing - do you have uboot?  Something chip-specific in the way of bootstrap?  There is so much to think about if doing this from scratch, you are best off finding a working configuration for your board or one like it, even if for an older linux kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me specify my requirements. I need to compile a kernel module for my target platform running 2.6.21 kernel. If I run file command on some other module that runs successfully on the target system, it shows  "ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, MIPS, MIPS32 version 1 (SYSV), not stripped".

Comment: I downloaded 2.6.21 kernel, update $ARCH and $CROSS_COMPILE and compiled the kernel. Now when I specify this kernel source path in my module makefile it builds a module which is for MIPSIII, and MSB. The linux-2.6.21/.config does not have CONFIG_MIPS32 set and CONFIG_LITTLE_ENDIAN set. So I thought I need to configure the kernel (at least modify these two options) before building my module against this kernel. Am I thinking in the right way? If not what should be my approach?

Comment: Also, please let me know if these two option (mips32 and 'little endian') can be specified in my module Makefile. What would be the make line then?

Comment: The linux kernel is configured by a file called .config in its top level directory and editable with various tools such as 'make menuconfig'. If you already have a kernel running on your board, you can try to find its config file, for example it has become common (but not universal) practice to have a gzipped copy of the .config appear as /proc/config.gz in the running system

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the issue. In my kernel configuration, machine selection was wrong so MIPS32, LITTLE_ENDIAN flag were not set in the configuration. After a few tries I have been able to sort out the right option and now I can build my module with this configurations. Thanks a lot for all the help.

Thanks,
Souvik